# html form send data of upload file to php page, I want to handle it on php page

Tags: php, html

HTML code is below

Upload Your pic only in jpg (Less 1 MB)

```
    <input type="file" title="Upload Your pic in jpg (Less 1 MB)" accept="image/jpeg" required="" class="select-style" tabindex="1" name="file[]"  multiple />
```

PHP code is below:

```
echo $_POST[$_FILES['file[]']];
echo $_POST[$_FILES["file"]["size"]];
```

Comment: Use `$_FILES[]` without the post array.

Comment: I am sending data from html page to Php page it did not handle if I use only $_FILES[].

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: What does handle mean?

Answer (score 1):

Your fomr must contain

> **enctype="multipart/form-data"**

**Like :-**

```
<form name="upload" id="upload" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: I also use enctype="multipart/form-data" it. Kindly understand my question, I have two pages one is html and second is php Now I send upload file and want to use on php page

Answer (score 0):

You can use $_FILES['file']['size'][0]; to get size of uploaded file

Hope this will help you

Thanks

Comment: Kindly understand my question, I have two pages one is html and second is php Now I send upload file and want to use on php page

Answer (score 0):

Ok..

**here is my HTML Page** page name stack.html

```
<form name="upload" id="upload" method="post" action="stack.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" title="Upload Your pic in jpg (Less 1 MB)" accept="image/jpeg" required="" class="select-style" tabindex="1" name="file[]"  multiple />



     <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**and here my PHP page** page name stack.php

```
<?php

if(!empty($_FILES)){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_FILES);
    echo "</pre>";
    exit;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

See if it gives any luck. Try it in php file..

```
foreach($_FILES as $file){
    print_r($file['size']);
    print_r($file['name']);
    //if you want total size of all images
    echo array_sum($file['size']);
    //if you want individual name
    for($i=0;$i<count($file['name']);$i++){
        echo $file['name'][$i];
        echo $file['size'][$i];
    }

}
```